# Django allowed host with debug= false not working even with localhost and 127.0.0.1 parameters set

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

Im trying to create a 404 custom template , i set **DEBUG=False** in my local settings.py, and set allowed host like this:

```
ALLOWED_HOST=['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']
```

But i still get this when i try to run server:

```
CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False.
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Try setting ALLOWED_HOSTS instead of ALLOWED_HOST !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error is caused by a missing character in the setting and its solution is so obvious that won't offer anything to the community...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ALLOWED_HOSTS` must be set. Not `ALLOWED_HOST`